# Microsoft Power Point displaying a blank slide

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, powerpoint

This is the basic program to write text in ppt using apache poi from java. But after execution, the created slide when opened using Microsoft PowerPoint displays a blank slide with no information. But the same when opened with Kingsoft ppt shows text at the beginning in a vertical line. Please help.

```
XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
XSLFSlide slide = ppt.createSlide();

XSLFTextBox shape = slide.createTextBox();
XSLFTextParagraph p = shape.addNewTextParagraph();

XSLFTextRun r1 = p.addNewTextRun();
r1.setText("The");
r1.setFontColor(Color.blue);
r1.setFontSize(24);
```

Comment: My requirement is to create a template, so i can't use any predefined slide layout other than BLANK. But when i use a Blank slide and the code above, i get the above mentioned problem.

Comment: Looks like this is straight out of the Cookbook. https://poi.apache.org/slideshow/xslf-cookbook.html#Text What version of POI are you using? Mixed versions? What version of PowerPoint?

Comment: This was solved, the reason was the textBox was not having an anchor to be placed in ppt. Thanks for the reply